# How to use nearly related parameters retrieve the same result

Tags: java, nearest-neighbor

I am building an sms based application that will retrieve railway schedules.Now the problem that I am facing is that if the user types the wrong name of a particular station(Suppose he writes 'Kolkta' instead of 'Kolkata') then my app would not be able to forward the result of query that has got nearest match to it.How will I do it?Is there an API in java for this?

Comment: @anyan Are you looking to return an error message, or make a best guess at what they _meant_ to type?

Comment: @MartyE I want to make a best guess at what they meant to type..

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) provides support you want in java.

Answer (score 0):

Lucence Apache sounds promising, but if you want something more straightforward that you can cook at home very easily, you can try computing the minimal [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the user input and the entire set of railway names. This is a measurement of similarity between strings and can be computed very efficiently (especially in your case, where the strings are very short).

The link above contains a scary mathematical formula but this is the nature of all formal representations. They are scary. Scroll a bit downwards a you will find the extremely short pseudo code for the algorithm (*almost* copy paste).